# How to initialize IEnumerable<Object> that be empty and allow to Concat to it?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, concatenation, argumentnullexception

I tried this code for adding `b` to `books`:

```
IEnumerable<Book> books =null;
foreach (Book b in context.Books.AsEnumerable())
    if (someConditions)
       books = books.Concat(new[] {b});
```

but gives me this error on last line of code:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: first

it seems that `null` `Collection` could not concatenated. I use EF,so how should I initialize my `Collection` that have no thing in it and I could concatenate to it?

Comment: you can not run method `Concat` on null

Comment: IEnumerable<Book> books = new List<Book>();

Comment: @wudzik Ok now what should I do instead?

Comment: Nick gave you answer first :)

Comment: `IEnumerable<Book> books = Enumerable.Empty<Book>();`

Comment: @VyacheslavVolkov That should be an answer.

Comment: `var books = context.Books.Where(b=> condition(b)).ToList();`

Comment: Others have answered your question. But it's still very inefficient, and somewhat ugly, to create an `IEnumerable<Book>` by concatting a lot of length-1 arrays of type `Book[]`. Consider filtering your books with Linq `Where` as in @Damith's comment, or maybe rewrite to use `yield return b;` from the loop (extract this loop to a new method, an _iterator block_).

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Linq is designed to query why would you manually build a list like that when Linq does it for you

Comment: Perhaps you have a good reason you simply left out, but why would you not simply change `books = books.Concat(new[] {b});` to `books = books == null ? new[]{b} : books.Concat(new[] {b});`. Still I question why your `books` variable is an `IEnumerable` in the first place? Do you not own it, i.e. did you get it like that from somewhere else in your code?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

It seams all you want to do is filter your context.Books by some criteria.

```
IEnumerable<Book> books = context.Books.Where(b => someConditions);
```

If you still need the empty IEnumerable you can just call Enumerable.Empty():

```
IEnumerable<Book> books = Enumerable.Empty<Book>();
```

Answer (score 28):

```
IEnumerable<Book> books = new List<Book>();
```

Answer (score 5):

This is what you are trying to do:

```
IEnumerable<Book> books = Enumerable.Empty<Book>();
books = books.Concat(context.Books.AsEnumerable().Where(b => someCondition));
```

Alternatively you can do this if you like to start from null:

```
IEnumerable<Book> books = null;
var moreBooks = context.Books.AsEnumerable().Where(b => someCondition);
books = books == null ? moreBooks : books.Concat(moreBooks);
```

...although I have several question as to why you want / need to do things this way.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I'd just go with:

```
IEnumerable<Book> books = new Book[0];
```

rather than using a List.

Comment: Although I would still use `Enumerable.Empty<T>` rather than this, because it avoids creating new array instances, this is still better than creating a `List<T>` as per the accepted answer because there is an optimization in .net that caches Enumerators for zero length arrays!

Comment: @AnorZaken I do agree that `Enumberable.Empty<T>` would be better (since it's more descriptive), but note that it does still (lazily) create an empty array.

Comment: Yes but it does so only once for each type T, using the type-system and JIT to make it lazy and cached (generic static readonly field). So `Enumerable.Empty` still comes out on top. (We don't know how many times that line there will be called - maybe a 1000 times per second, only OP knows.)

Answer (score 1):

You need create books as a IEnumerable empty object like List, but need remember to call, after loop, ToList() on books. For example:

> ```
>         IEnumerable<int> books = new List<int>();
>         IEnumerable<int> books2 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
>
>
>         foreach (int b in books2)
>             if (b > 2)
>                 books = (new[] { b }).Concat(books);
>
>         books = books.ToList();
> ```

Comment: Or use Enumerable.Empty<Book>() like Vyacheslav Volkov mentioned above.